# How to trace which HashMap throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, concurrency, hashmap

In my application I have several HashMaps. One of them do throw ConcurrentModificationException every now and then. Problem is that I do not know how to trace which Map actually throws it, and when the ConcurrentModification happens. The stack trace does not show any line numbers to where it happens. The begin of the stack trace looks liks this:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:806)
at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:838)
at com.parse.ParseTraverser.traverseInternal(ParseTraverser.java:87)
at com.parse.ParseTraverser.traverse(ParseTraverser.java:137)
at com.parse.ParseObject.collectFetchedObjects(ParseObject.java:817)
at com.parse.ParseObject.access$700(ParseObject.java:49)
at com.parse.ParseObject$13.then(ParseObject.java:1487)
at com.parse.ParseObject$13.then(ParseObject.java:1484)
at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't evaluate which `HashMap` is modified at the same time by two operations (classic example is a removal in a loop) you can always use `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I still wanted to try to figure out which map it was so I could see where the problem was. Anyway, is ConcurrentHashMap guaranteed  to not throw ConcurrentModificationException? I read the docs, and in my understanding it should not happen, but after I just tried to make all my hashMaps concurrent (I think I got all of them) I still receive this error sometimes.

Comment: A ConcurrentHashMap is synchronized but is not save from throwing any ConcurrentModificationException. (as mentioned in the answer: removal f.e.)

Comment: As long as you're not passing around the iterator of you ConcurrentHashMap (each thread uses it's own iterator) it should be safe.